# How to put footer?

Tags: lwuit

I want to put a footer , a copyright , on the bottom of my Form : even if the main content is larger in height then I want the footer always visible , and there is a vertical scrollbar associated with the main content. Here is a suggestive image :

[image]

How to accomplish that ?

Comment: Are you using LWUIT or Codename One?

Comment: I use LWUIT , I am old game lol.

Comment: LWUIT for Android will cause serious problems and have some performance issues on newer devices since Android 4.x changed pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a BorderLayout. The footer goes into south. You need additional nesting, and your new main container goes into center. You need make sure that this main container is set to be scrollable.